# Error when use javascript mouseover from an array?

Tags: javascript

```
<a href=""></a>
<textarea></textarea>
<object></object>
<img src="" />
<div id="content">content</div>
<div class="test">test</div>
```

And javascript

```
oj = ['a', '#content', '.test'];
oj.forEach(function(val) {
   val.onmouseover = function() {
      alert("Mouseouver !!!");
   }
});
```

When I mouseover this object, result not alert, how to fix it ?

Comment: `oj` is an array of strings. Not DOM elements.

Answer (score 1):

If you're about to use jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a, #content, .test').on("mouseover", function(){
        alert("Mouseouver !!!");
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jcWLn/

Answer (score 0):

You are not adressing the dom objects which is the first problem.
The array content points to css classes.
You have to fetch individual objects and attach onMouseOver function to them.
Have a look at document.getElementById() function...